# Struts2 - Showing validation errors on page

Tags: java, validation, struts2

I'm using **simple** theme in my struts2 application. In my action's `validate()` method, if i add validation error messages using `addFieldError(fieldName, message)`, the error message is not showing up in my view page. I guess this is because I use the **simple** theme.

So, how do I show struts2 validation errors in my screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer: it's using `<s:fieldError/>` tag in my JSP file. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, there is a typing error in you tag. Correct tag is:

```
<s:fielderror/>
```